# How can I rerender a blaze template when an input value changes on a different template?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template called 'orientation' that contains arguments for a series of sliders whose values depend on an input from a different template called 'selector'.

When I change the input value on the selector template I would like orientation template to rerender with the new values for my sliders which are calculated using the new input value.

What would be the best way to do this, should I completely rerender the template or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: what is the relationship between these 2 templates? parent/child? both children of a parent template? or...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Session variable. You need to use

```
Session.set('variablename', value)
```

to set the variable in your selector template, and

```
Session.get('variablename')
```

to retrieve its value it in the template that needs it for stuff. Meteor reactivity should do the rest ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Mathieu's session suggestion works great - Michel also mentioned reactive variables. You can use the `ReactiveVar` package, to achieve much the same result as using `Session`, as long as you define, export and import the variable accordingly (assuming you're using Meteor 1.3 or later).

e.g. in Template A:

```
//... set something to the Reactive Var in an event handler, e.g.

import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
export let selector = new ReactiveVar();

Template.templateA.events({
  'click .something':(event)=>{
    selector.set('somethingImportant');
  }
})
```

And in Template B:

```
// ... making sure you import the reactive var

import { selector } from '/path/to/templateA';

Template.templateB.helpers({
  getSelector:()=>{
    return selector.get()
  }
});
```

More on [ReactiveVar](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) can be read over on Meteor's docs. One key thing from the docs to note is that:

> ReactiveVars can hold any value, while Session variables are limited
>   to JSON or EJSON.

Which might be worth bearing in mind depending on how you're handling the data driving the reactivity of the sliders.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to implement overservables which you can use to behave in reactive mode when the value changes.

Comment: While that is one possible solution it is far from the simplest one.

Comment: What's that solution?

Comment: `Session` variable or reactive variable. That's the normal meteoric pattern for reactively communicating state across templates.